# Bootstrap navigation dropdown for jQuery 1.5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in conjunction with XenForo, which only likes old versions of jQuery. The problem is that the twitter bootstrap plugins are not backwards-compatible, and cause issues when run. I don't want to downgrade bootstrap because a load of bug fixes have been made to that specific component. The main problem is [the .on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which does not exist in earlier versions of jQuery.

I'm tempted to write my own (seems pretty simple) but want to know if there is an easier way of doing stuff. Can I just insert the jQuery code for the .on function somewhere?

Upgrading jQuery is also not an option, as it breaks XenForo - here's [their community thread about this](http://xenforo.com/community/threads/upgrade-jquery.25126/). Any ideas?

See also

- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js

Comment: You should be able to make an .on function that just passes on the call out to .bind or .live instead, yes. However it might be better to try and get XenForo compatible with later jQuery - but I don't know XenForo so I've no idea what the problems might be.

Comment: Just tried it, pretty much breaks absolutely everything to do with JavaScript.
I did a find + replace for .on with .live, but that never worked. I need to look to see if the arguments differ or something (saw no errors when I did it like this though, just didn't do the job)

Comment: Trying it with .bind instead...

Comment: Yeah @Rup, bind + live appear to work (no console errors or anything) but simply fail to work when clicking on the navigation bar

Comment: It's not simply a case of replacing the function, sorry - you're right, the arguments are different. You'll need to test the types of the arguments to work out what you've got and then you'll need to call the .bind or .live on the selector (second argument if present, else use the document I guess) - and probably more mappings. It ought to be possible to replicate the logic but it's not going to be trivial.

Comment: I'd also missed that XenForo is commercial and so I assume closed-source/obfuscated and so you likely won't be able to fix it yourself, but you could try and find out where it's going wrong (it's trying to use something that's been removed, or it's relying on a jQuery bug, or something else) then replicate that in the latest jQuery instead. There may even be compatibility wrappers written by someone else you can just take.